# Making Bank account in Python 3

Tags: python

Need help with the code below i need it to basically print out the name of the account holder and their balance when a pin is entered into the program. Also any advice would be nice in how to implement the ability to add and remove accounts from the program, any help is much appreciated.`enter code here`

```
class BankAccount:

     # constructor or initializer
    def __init__(self, name, money, pin):
         self.__name = name
         self.__balance = money   # __balance is private now, so it is only accessible inside the class
         self.__pin = pin
   def pincheck(self):
       pin = input("Enter Pin")
       if pin == self.__pin
       return True
       else:
           print("Error try again")

    def deposit(self, money):
         self.__balance += money

    def withdraw(self, money):
         if self.__balance > money :
             self.__balance -= money
             return money
         else:
             return "Insufficient funds"

    def checkbalance(self):
         return self.__balance


b1 = BankAccount('Obi Ezeakachi', 5000, 1111)
b2 = BankAccount('Tasha St.Patrick', 80000, 2222)
b3 = BankAccount('Tommy Egan', 7000, 3333)
d1 = 0
d2 = 0
d3 = 0


print("Obi Ezeakachi: £",b1.checkbalance())
y1 = int(input("Enter 1 if you want to make a withdrawal, enter 2 if you don't"))
if y1 == 1:
   w1= int(input("How much do you want to withdraw"))
   print("Withdrawal: £",b1.withdraw(w1))
else:
   d1= int(input("How much do you want to deposit"))   
   b1.deposit(d1)   
   print("Current Balance:",b1.checkbalance())                                        

print("Tasha St.Patrick:",b2.checkbalance())
y1 = int(input("Enter 1 if you want to make a withdrawal, enter 2 if you don't"))
if y1 == 1:
   w2= int(input("How much do you want to withdraw"))
   print(b2.withdraw(w2))
else:
   d2= int(input("How much do you want to deposit"))
   b2.deposit(d2)

print("Tommy Egan:",b3.checkbalance())
y1 = int(input("Enter 1 if you want to make a withdrawal, enter 2 if you don't"))   
if y1 == 1:
   w3= int(input("How much do you want to withdraw"))
   print("Withdrawal:",b3.withdraw(w3))
else:
   d3= int(input("How much do you want to deposit"))
   b3.deposit(d3) 

print("Current Balance:",b3.checkbalance())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider saving all the details in a dictionary with the primary key as the name and pin & balance as secondary keys. Then, you can save it to a json file.

```
import json 
accdict ={}
accdict['Obi'] = {'Name':'Obi Ezeakachi','Pin':1111,'Balance': 5000}
```

Continue for all the accounts.

```
with open('accounts.json','w') as f:
     f.write(json.dumps(accdict))
```

You can now manipulate this dictionary however you want and repeat.

Also, you should call the pin checker function before making a transaction. If you're serious about it and want it make it like an ATM, use threading to check for pin in the background while you access the details and interact with the user.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to add the inverted commas. Copy pasted that name.

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to python can you explain to me what the json file is,  I was also going to make the pin checker a function. But verifying the pin how I am supposed to link that function with the code that carries out the deposits and withdrawals of the account

Comment: You can start reading about json from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: As for pin checking, simply add `if b1.pincheck():` above `if y1==1:` so that the code executes only when the pincheck function returns true. Note that it is b2 for next and b3 for last.

Comment: Thanks will try but can you show me how to store object instances within a dictionary

Comment: You can save any instance in dictionary in the same way. `dict = {'key': object}` and access it with `dict[key]`.

Comment: This is how i've done the dictionary and function but it won't work kept getting an error saying TypeError: pincheck() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given  
         
    def pincheck(pin):
        if pin == data[1111]:
           return True
        else:
            return False;
 

data = {'1111': b1 , '2222': b2, '3333': b3}

Comment: also what am i supposed to to the function so it checks the pain against all the values within the dictionary